# Materialize css footer color white issue

Tags: html, css, materialize

I tried to make a footer and give it a white background color using materialize css but it gives me a grey background color. I tried different colors and it works. The [link](http://materializecss.com/color.html) to materialize colors.

HTML:

```
<footer class="page-footer white">
 <div class="footer-copyright">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="left-align">&copy; 2016, Company</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Which should mean it still gets overridden somewhere. Right click and chose "Inspect" and you will be able to see its CSS

Comment: I already did that and there's no problem in css. Anyways the issue already solve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the class to the internal div, too:

```
<footer class="page-footer white">
 <div class="footer-copyright white">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="left-align">&copy; 2016, Company</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Oh c'mon! this solves the issue. I missed the white under copyright div. Thanks!